# Python: split data frame row into multiple rows

Tags: python, dataframe

How can I split column values into many rows ?

For example :

I have the following headers: `title, url, body, comments`. I scraped this data and  exported it as a csv file. My comment column has more than one comment as shown below :

```
{'comment': [u'Have you never see Eric Pickles?', u'Looks a bit unrealistic'], 'name': [u'gruniadreader666', u'Dowling1981']}
```

I want each comment to be in its own row.

Comment: what do you mean with many rows?

Comment: @levi: for just 1 url  i can have many comments which falls in just one row but i need each comment to be in it's own row

Answer (score 0):

Use 'DataFrame.from_dict'

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: d = {'comment': [u'Have you never see Eric Pickles?', u'Looks a bit unrealistic'], 'name': [u'gruniadreader666', u'Dowling1981']}


In [3]: pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='columns')
Out[3]: 
                            comment              name
0  Have you never see Eric Pickles?  gruniadreader666
1           Looks a bit unrealistic       Dowling1981
```

You can also orient around the index, but that's not what you want in this case.

```
In [4]: pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
Out[4]: 
                                        0                        1
comment  Have you never see Eric Pickles?  Looks a bit unrealistic
name                     gruniadreader666              Dowling1981
```